# error when run speech recognition on raspberry pi

Tags: python, linux, speech-recognition, raspberry-pi4

I am trying connect microphone on raspberry pi 4 model B then showing the error:

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM sysdefault
```

My python code is:

```
import speech_recognition as sr


try:
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    print("What do you think to say? ")
    with sr.Microphone() as src:
        r.energy_threshold = 4000 # to prevent occurance more than person can be spoken
        audio = r.listen(src)
    print("Recognized the speech.....")
    pattern = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en_US') # ar-EG
    print(pattern)
except sr.UnknownValueError as U:
    pass
```

Comment: What library is throwing those errors?

Comment: SpeechRecognition Library

Comment: If it's the `import` that fails, the rest of the code can be deleted, as it's not part of the problem. This may be a bug in the library you could report.

Comment: It's not a problem of importing a library i am trying running only import speech_recognition and that was the result it is run successfully and when adding other code with library can see the error

Comment: It's worth trimming out whatever code doesn't get run because of the errors. Is it `sr.Recognizer()` or what? Whatever the case, be sure that your sound device(s) are configured correctly, as with Linux there are often a number of things you need to do to confirm those are working. Like, can you get the mic to work in any other app?

Comment: the Headphone is running speakers and microphone successfully on Windows but when connected to Raspberry Pi 4 speakers successfully and the microphone not running it.

Comment: You'll need to confirm that Linux is properly identifying the device(s) and is hooking them up to whatever Linux audio system you're using.

Comment: This is what is required of me and give error